# ffmpeg giving frame_size to zero on using AV_CODEC_ID_PCM_MULAW encoder

Tags: c++, audio, ffmpeg, decoding, libavformat

I am trying to initialize an encoder for AV_CODEC_ID_PCM_MULAW using ffmpeg but when I initialize mContext it gives 0 frame_size is it correct? if it is correct then how can I can I find the frame_size or nb_sampels of the raw data .The raw data is in pcmu format. And also av_samples_get_buffer_size function returns -22 which is invalid parameter. why??

```
   avcodec_register_all();
   mCodec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_PCM_MULAW);
    if(mCodec == NULL) {
            return -1;
            }
   mContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(mCodec);
    if(mContext == NULL) {
            return -1;
        }
   mContext->channels = numberOfChannel;
   mContext->sample_rate = sampelRate;
   mContext->bit_rate = bitRate;
   mContext->sample_fmt = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16;
   mContext->channel_layout = AV_CH_LAYOUT_MONO;
   mContext->channels = 1;
   mContext->sample_rate=8;
        if(mCodecType == Audio_Encoder && !checkSampleFmt(mCodec,mContext->sample_fmt)) {
            return -1;
         }
    if(avcodec_open2(mContext, mCodec, NULL) < 0) {
            return -1;
        }
    mFrame = av_frame_alloc();
    mFrame->nb_samples = mContext->frame_size;
    mFrame->format = mContext->sample_fmt;
    mFrame->channel_layout = 
    mContext->channel_layout;
    int len = av_samples_get_buffer_size(NULL, mContext->channels,
    mContext->frame_size, mContext->sample_fmt, 0);
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/39274304/902217